# Custom validation rule messages when uploading files in Kohana

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm, kohana-3.3

I would like to create a custom error message when uploading file fails validation using Kohana 3.3. This code is getting the rules and checking them:

```
$image = $_FILES['image'];

$rules = Model_Image::get_file_rules();
$validation = Validation::factory($_FILES)->rules('img_file', $rules);

if(!$validation->check())
{
    throw new ORM_Validation_Exception('', $validation);
}

if($image['size'] > 0)
{
    // upload
}
```

The rules:

```
public static function get_file_rules()
{
    return array(
        array('Upload::valid'),
        array('Upload::not_empty', array(':value')),
        array('Upload::type', array(':value', array('jpg'))),
        array('Upload::size', array(':value', '10M'))
    );
}
```

When a file is not added it throws ORM_Validation_Exception. When I `print_r($e->errors)` I get the following:

```
Array ( [img_file] => .img_file.Upload::not_empty )
```

I would like to create a custom error message. At the moment I have the message file `/messages/image.php` with the following contents:

```
return array(
    'filename_unique' => 'Filename must be unique',


    'img_file' => array(
        'Upload::not_empty' => 'Add something!!',
    )
);
```

How can I create a custom message for this?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [the Validation guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/security/validation#a-complete-example), you should use `$validation->errors()`.

If you want to store your messages in `/messages/image.php`, you have to write `throw new ORM_Validation_Exception('', $validation->errors('image'));` to make sure Kohana is looking for the good file containing your messages.

More informations in the [API Browser](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Validation#errors).